# Tricky definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve 
$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}\arcsin x dx$$

I tried doing integration by parts with $u = \arcsin x$ and dv = $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but to get $v$, I assume I need to do integration by parts again: 
$$u = x, v = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1-x^2} x + \arcsin x)$$
$$du = dx, dv = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
and subsituting it back gives me a really hairy expression. Am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: Up to a constant factor, $x$ is the derivative of $x^2$. Us the chain rule (or a substitution) to find a primitive of $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$, not integration by parts.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the result $\frac{2}{9}$ and the antiderivate $\frac{1}{9}(-x^3-3(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}arcsin(x)+3x)$

Comment: Possibly silly question: doesn't substituting $x = \sin u$ work?

Comment: @Hurkyl It will work, $x=\sin u$, I have just tried it.  However it is a bit longer it seems since we end up with two integrals to do by partial integration, but this seems like a more natural substitution I agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(1-x^2)'=-2x$. Now use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) with regards to $x\,\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and apply [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) for $f'(x)=x\,\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $g(x)=\arcsin x$. Since $\arcsin'x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ , you will find a nice simplification. :-)